# React Native View on top of react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

## Feature request

[Can I Show Simple React Native View on the Top of MapView? if it is not how can i do it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMxvO.png)

Please Help Me out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some view with an absolute positioning:

```
<View>
  <Map />
  <View style={{position: 'absolute'}}/>
</View
```

You can use `top, bottom, right, left` style props to achieve the positioning that you want.
Here is [a snack with an example of achieving that](https://snack.expo.dev/mrZFoDojS).
And a link to official [Layout Props docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#position).